# Java - Rendering Image in JTable

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I'm writing a program to play a game of cards. I already made the game work, and effectively play it, but now I have decided to add images of cards (right now it works but using the names of cards, like "As of Spades",  instead of an icon to represent them).

In my program, I use `JTable`s to organize the cards and for the selection of them in the various `JDialog`s I put them in (one dialog for swapping the cards in hand, another to select card to discard, etc.)

What I tried, and I personally like how it'd work, its to make a `JTable` with 8 columns and 1 row of cells for each card. And inside of each cell put a image of the card. Then I'd select a cell to select a card, or use a `JButtonGroup` outside of the table.

```
    DefaultTableModel dtModel = new DefaultTableModel(COL_NAMES, 0) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            if (getRowCount() > 0)
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            return super.getColumnClass(column);
        }
    };

    //add the columns to the model:
    if (dtModel.getColumnCount() == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            dtModel.addColumn(COL_NAMES[i]);
        }
    }
    //add a row to the model:
    if (dtModel.getRowCount() == 0) {
        Object[] data = {new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel()}; 
        dtModel.addRow(data);
    }

    jTable1.setModel(dtModel);

    //set the size of the table, but I think I got it wrong:
    jScrollPane1.setSize(400, jScrollPane1.getColumnHeader().getHeight() + jTable1.getRowHeight());

    //here is the image I'm using:
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DeRipper\\Pictures\\Naipes\\oros_1s.jpg");

    //the loop where I set the image in all the cells. I scale the image into a smaller size:
    for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
        jTable1.setValueAt(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 65, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)), 0, i);
```

Where `"C:\\Users\\DeRipper\\Pictures\\Naipes\\oros_1s.jpg"` is the path to the card file. I was first testing my code by putting the same card image for all the cells.

At first glance I got the desired result, the images were displayed correctly, but when clicking on them a couple of times the table would stop rendering them and instead showed the `toString()` value of the images:

[Card Images in JTable(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRBvo.png)

[Card Images in JTable(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAHLI.png)

And then the images would not show on the table again. I just need the user to be able to click on the images and not disappear.

Well, thanks for reading.

DeR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object[] data = {new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel()}; 
dtModel.addRow(data);
```

Don't add `JLabel`s to the model. Instead you need to add an `ImageIcon`.

Then the `JTable` will use the Icon renderer to display the image.

[Simple Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615516/131872)

> but when clicking on them a couple of times  the table would stop rendering them and instead showing the "toString()" value of the images:

If you are editing the cells, then the default editor will just save the `toString()` representation of the object back to the TableModel. So you might want to override the `isCellEditable(...)` method to turn editing off. Otherwise you would need a custom editor that knows how to edit and save an `ImageIcon`.