# To display image on jtable

Tags: java, swing

i am trying to display image on jtable cell.but it is showing some format like [ba.. like that.i want to get data from mysql and i want to show that in table format i am using jar file to display. even i have override tableranderer..showing identifier not found.thanks in advance.

```
class LabelRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                    int row, int column) {

                return (Component) value;
            }}
        table = new JTable();
        table.getColumn("image").setCellRenderer(new LabelRenderer());
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.180:3306/cardemo","root","sqladmin");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select  * from cardemo.imagetest");
            ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) ps.executeQuery();
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            label = new JLabel("");
            label.setBounds(464, 24, 122, 155);
            contentPane.add(label);
```

Comment: The code you've posted give me no hint about what's wrong. Please try to create an app without a database connection, and when you get problems, ask us with a [mcve]. Please also read about [tables in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [images in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614875/how-to-set-icon-in-a-column-of-jtable/5615516#5615516