# How to retrieve image of type blob from MySQL in JTable using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have created a simple application to display images from a database. I have a table in a MySQL database with a column of type `BLOB`.

When I retrieve an image from the table it just contains: "javax.swing.ImageIcon@2143ca6".

**My code:**

```
String[] columntabelNames = {"Images"};
DefaultTableModel modelas = new DefaultTableModel(columntabelNames, 0);

Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs;

try {
  Connection conn = getConnection();
  stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

  ResultSet rs1;
  rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT IMAGES_IMAGE FROM dc_images");
  if (rs1.next()) {

    byte[] imgData = rs1.getBytes("IMAGES_IMAGE");
    ImageIcon imagIcon = new ImageIcon(imgData);
    Image im = imagIcon.getImage();
    Image myImage = im.getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon newImageIcon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
    lblimage.setIcon(newImageIcon);

    Object data[] = {newImageIcon};
    modelas.addRow(data);
  }
  tabelImage.setModel(modelas);

} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614875/how-to-set-icon-in-a-column-of-jtable/5615516#5615516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I retrieve an image from the table it just contains: "javax.swing.ImageIcon@2143ca6".

The default renderer for the JTable simply invokes the toString() method on the object so you are seeing the toString() for the ImageIcon.

You need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your `TableModel` (or `JTable`) to return `Icon.class`, then the table will use an Icon renderer.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Renderers/Editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Image im = ImageIO.read((ImageInputStream) new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData)));
```

Comment: I'm trying you code but not working, my problem is when I add a ImageIcon  "newImageIcon" to Array "data []" , and add Array "data []" to Jtabel  "tabelimage ", because JLabel "lblimage" display the image retrieve database. thank you